# Metaio SDK - XCode 6 Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, sdk, metaio

I have a metaio project for iOS that was working just fine with XCode 5. Since switching to XCode 6 for testing with iOS8 I've ran into the problem of 6 new Mach-O linker errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEventEditViewController", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in metaioSDK(XDtLkdmsHtXjGTCxiIGVbMqenrFYqNevtLOSg)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEvent", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in metaioSDK(xhvNiLkUYIhedEvQjYEaAfH)
    objc-class-ref in metaioSDK(XDtLkdmsHtXjGTCxiIGVbMqenrFYqNevtLOSg)
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerViewController", referenced from:
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ASMoviePlayerViewController in metaioSDK(ASMoviePlayerViewController.o)
    _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MoviePlayerViewController in metaioSDK(MoviePlayerViewController.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEventStore", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in metaioSDK(xhvNiLkUYIhedEvQjYEaAfH)
    objc-class-ref in metaioSDK(XDtLkdmsHtXjGTCxiIGVbMqenrFYqNevtLOSg)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerViewController", referenced from:
    _OBJC_CLASS_$_ASMoviePlayerViewController in metaioSDK(ASMoviePlayerViewController.o)
    _OBJC_CLASS_$_MoviePlayerViewController in metaioSDK(MoviePlayerViewController.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to add three new frameworks to my build phases.

1. Navigate to build phases
2. Add the following new frameworks

   - MediaPlayer
   - EventKitUI
   - EventKit

Done...